# java - passing a double value by reference

Tags: java

how can I pass a double value by reference in java?

example:

```
Double a = 3.0;
Double b = a;
System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b);
a = 5.0;
System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b);
```

this code prints:

```
a: 3 b: 3
a: 5 b: 3
```

and my problem is to get it to print:

```
a: 3 b: 3
a: 5 b: 5
```

my goal:
I'm writing an expert system in jess, in that application a segment would have a double value for it's length, now that double value isn't in a single segment; it's in many other segments, proportionality classes..etc, all of which are referencing to it, waiting it to change so that they could possibly meet some rules.

if I can't get that double to change, I can't have a certain rule fire which contains an object that references to that double value.

Comment: Nothing in Java is passed by reference.  Everything is passed by value.

Comment: @Chris or to be more precise http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 11):

Java doesn't support pointers, so you can't point to a's memory directly (as in C / C++).

Java does support references, but references are only references to Objects.  Native (built-in) types cannot be referenced.  So when you executed (autoboxing converted the code for you to the following).

Double a = new Double(3.0);

That means that when you execute

```
Double b = a;
```

you gain a reference to a's Object.  When you opt to change a (autoboxing will eventually convert your code above to this)

```
a = new Double(5.0);
```

Which won't impact b's reference to the previously created `new Double(3.0)`.  In other words, you can't impact b's reference by manipulating a directly (or there's no "action at a distance" in Java).

That said, there are other solutions

```
public class MutableDouble() {

   private double value;

   public MutableDouble(double value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   public double getValue() {
     return this.value;
   }

   public void setValue(double value) {
     this.value = value;
   }
 }

 MutableDouble a = new MutableDouble(3.0);
 MutableDouble b = a;

 a.setValue(5.0);
 b.getValue(); // equals 5.0
```

Answer (score 7):

The wrapper types are immutable in Java. Once they are created, their value cannot be changed (except via reflection magic ofcourse). Why are you trying to do what you're doing?

Edit:
Just to elaborate, when you set:

```
a = 5.0;
```

What actually ends up happening is something like:

```
a = new Double(5.0);
```

If double were mutable, you could have done something like

```
a.setValue(5.0);// this would have worked for mutable objects, but not in this case
```

You can of course write your own class, but there are a lot of pitfalls here, so it's best to explain you're goal

Comment: I'm writing an expert system to solve geometrical problems in jess, and a certain double value say, the length of a segment is a part of many classes, now I could make classes to hold segments instead of double values, but that'd cause a mini class explosion

Comment: Nope, you are correct in having classes hold "Segments" rather than Doubles. This makes the intention clear, and in case you ever modify the game to use something other than doubles, there is a smaller impact. Dont worry over too many classes, in OOP, there is (almost) no such thing as too many classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`MutableDouble`](http://people.apache.org/~bayard/commons-lang-3.0-snapshot-api/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableDouble.html) from commons-lang.

But not that this has nothing to do with pass-by-reference - you are not passing anything.

Comment: actually, the copy constructor in double is passing the object by value, and I wanted it to pass it by reference, apologies if the question seemed obscure

Comment: @Ouais - in Java you cant pass the reference itself - you pass the value of the reference. When you do `a=5.0`, it's not the same `a` that's getting set to 5.0 - if that was true then `b` would have 5 as well.

Answer (score 2):

@Title itself: You can't without "dirty" tricks. The easiest method is to pass an array - or a class containing the field. Changes to those will be reflected just fine.

But your problem is something completely different: Doubles are immutable, so every change to it will return a new value. There's nothing you can do about that, apart from implementing your own class.

Comment: already considered passing classes, but it seemed like an ugly thing to do

Answer (score 1):

Double is immutable in Java.  The assignment a = 5.0 is not changing the Double value of a.  It is actually creating an entirely new Double object and changing the value of the pointer that a holds to point at that new object.  If you want to be able to change the value without changing the reference, you need to make a mutable Double.

```
public class MutableDouble {
  private Double value;

  public Double getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Double value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value != null ? value.toString() : "null";
  }
}
```

Then you would call a.setValue(5.0); and both would change.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. In java you can not select the way (by value/by ref) by which parameters will be passed to a method.

Answer (score 0):

Same that Java not pass any primitive as reference exists alternatives on Java to reference any value if that value is hosted on one array that is one object. For that you can, for example, passing parameters to method via unitary array:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         double[] arr =  { 2.3535 };
         xDouble(arr);
         System.out.printf("The 2x double for reference is: %.2f\n", arr[0]);
    }
    
    private static void xDouble(double[] dA) {
        dA[0]=dA[0]*2;
    }
    }

    Result: The 2x double for reference is: 4.71
```