# How to modify two Double objects in java function?

Tags: java

My function takes as input two Double objects, and I would like to modify them both
inside the function. It seems it is not possible, it seems java copies them inside
the function. How is this done in java, in c++ you pass by reference.

Thanks

Comment: `Double` objects are immutable. Your approach is impossible.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [java - passing a double value by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749251/java-passing-a-double-value-by-reference)

Answer (score 12):

Wrapper classes are immutable, that is the reason you were unable to modify them. One way is , you may create one class with these two attributes and pass it to the function, inside function, set new values to that object.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is wrap the `Double` objects into a Wrapper class, and modify the doubles stored in that object.
Otherwise, no other way, as the only value you will change is the local argument.

```
public class DoubleWrapper
{
  private double d1, d2; 
  public void setter(double newdouble){} 
  public double getter() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the double values in an array, you can modify array elements in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Java is call by value, so you're right: It must be done in another manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

First, all values in Java are pass-by-value. This means that, when an object X is sent to a function, that function holds a *new* version of X.

Second, you can't modify a `Double` value. You have to modify a `double`, and can convert from `Double d` to `double` by running `d.doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't be modifying arguments in Java (or perhaps any language)

Instead I suggest you return the values changed as an array

```
public static double[] square(double... doubles) {
     double[] ret = new double[doubles.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++)
         ret[i] = doubles[i] * doubles[i];
     return ret;
}
```

Ideally, you would have a class which wraps these doubles and you call a method to alter them

```
class MyDoubles {
     double d1, d2;

     public void squareDoubles() {
         d1 *= d1;
         d2 *= d2;
     }

     public String toString() { return "{ " + d1 +", " + d2 + "}"; }
}
```